# Paging on CMS page with product list not working correctly

Tags: cms, product-list

I have created a cms page

www.mysite.com/page

with the following code in the layout update XML, as mentioned in loads of sites on the net

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

But when I try using any of the toolbars, for example clicking page 2, it redirects to the homepage

www.mysite.com/?p=2

It is not retaining the current page, what is going wrong here?

Comment: I have narrowed this down to an extension issue

Recommend anyone having same issue to turn off each extension 1 by 1, see if it solves the issue

Comment: have you solved the issue or do you just know what extension the issue is in?

Comment: i fixed the issue. It was a paid extension - amasty layered navigation. But i heavily modified the code and don't have the latest version. So maybe it is fixed, or i caused it in the first place

Comment: You may want to close/answer the question then.